# Creating a changing number grid in Java

Tags: java

I'll preface this with the fact that this *is* for homework, so I am just looking for help in which direction to go for solving this problem.

Essentially, I'm supposed to use for-loops to create a number grid that iterates until a max is reached, then wraps around.

Ex:

```
012345
123450
234501
345012
450123
501234
```

I don't know why, but I can't figure this out for the life of me. I'm not allowed to use things like if-statements, so I'm really confused.

My code so far is just the for-loops that iterate but they don't iterate the way they're supposed to:

```
public static void square(int min, int max) {
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
        System.out.print(i);
        for(int j = min + 1; j <= max; j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
012345
112345
212345
312345
412345
512345
```

I understand that my code isn't setting the grid up to iterate the way I want it to, I'm just not sure of what direction to go down to fix it. I'm probably overthinking this, but I'm lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Using modular arithmetic would help. Can you think about a related Java operator?

Comment: It never even crossed my mind. Huh, I definitely see how that would work! Now I have to figure out a relationship. Thank you!